# Running MariaDB in a docker container using docker stack

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I'm trying to follow the instructions on https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/ but changing it to a single node MariaDB database.  I am using a `docker-compose.yml` file that looks like this...

```
version: "3"
services:
  database:
    image: mariadb:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: jeesample
      MYSQL_USER: jeeuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
    - webnet
    ports:
    - "3307:3306"
networks: 
  webnet:
```

Then I start it using

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml jeesample
```

However, when I look at `docker stack ps jeesample` I get the following:

```
ID            NAME                      IMAGE           NODE  DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE                   ERROR                      PORTS
9yjyzmi86aqm  jeesample_database.1      mariadb:latest  moby  Running        Running less than a second ago
gqamjzc2u1fw   \_ jeesample_database.1  mariadb:latest  moby  Shutdown       Failed 6 seconds ago            "task: non-zero exit (1)"
615zc8s0rts1   \_ jeesample_database.1  mariadb:latest  moby  Shutdown       Failed 18 seconds ago           "task: non-zero exit (1)"
pod5ldwn6p6v   \_ jeesample_database.1  mariadb:latest  moby  Shutdown       Failed 27 seconds ago           "task: non-zero exit (1)"
ma1gkri9os14   \_ jeesample_database.1  mariadb:latest  moby  Shutdown       Failed 37 seconds ago           "task: non-zero exit (1)"
```

Trying to connect to it using `jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3307/jeesample` from a SQL client on my local machine fails because I am unable to connect

Comment: nice to know, and ? can you elaborate your expectations?

Comment: Can't see a question...

Comment: "unable to connect" -- the text of the error is likely to give some clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of diagnosing this issue is to look at the logs.  To get the logs do `docker ps` to get a list of the containers then `docker logs -f <container ID>` to get the log result.  Since it is on a docker-compose the container may go away after a short while so the `-f` option will keep it connected until it terminates.

To resolve the issue which the logs say that there needs to be a password for the root user, I just needed to add

```
MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "true"
```

Although there are other options such has

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "blah" // visible on source
MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes" // not recommended
```